# ELF - .symtab section

Tags: x86, elf

How to force GCC to include the .symtab section for ELF executables/shared libraries? I have already tried using **-static** and **-ggdb** but it didn't work.

**EDIT**: *readelf -l* yields the following:

```
 Section to Segment mapping:
 Segment Sections...
  00     
  01     .interp 
  02     .interp .note.ABI-tag .note.gnu.build-id .gnu.hash .dynsym .dynstr .gnu.version .gnu.version_r .rela.dyn .rela.plt .init .plt .text .fini .rodata .eh_frame_hdr .eh_frame 
  03     .init_array .fini_array .dynamic .got .got.plt .data .bss 
  04     .dynamic 
  05     .note.ABI-tag .note.gnu.build-id 
  06     .eh_frame_hdr 
  07     
  08     .init_array .fini_array .dynamic .got
```

Comment: What makes you think there isn't one in the file? Possibly it is the tool you are using to display the files? Use `readelf` instead of `objdump` for example

Comment: Try using `-S`  with `readelf`. And to decode `symtab` use `-Ss`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default `.symtab` *is* included, you don't need to do anything to get it.

> readelf -l yields the following:

That command is used to list *segments*. Since you are interested in *sections*, you should use

```
readelf -WS $binary
```

instead.

Your binary could still be missing the `.symtab` section. If it does, the most common cause is a "stray" `-s` (strip) option on the link line (or running `strip` on the binary from a `Makefile`).